# Partial automation of interactive program with Expect

Tags: bash, input, automation, expect

I have an executable of a program, written in Fortran that needs interactive input, for example 20 inputs. What I want, is to give the first 19 inputs through input redirection but the last one from my keyboard. The reason is because when I run the program I get a message

```
file list_wall.dat written - modify it to group walls
modify wallList.dat (add flag type) - enter 1 when ready
```

So before I press 1, I need to modify a file manually and then press 1 manually. I tried to automate this using expect with the following code:

```
expect
spawn ./my_interactive_program 
set fh [open input_file.in r]
while {[gets $fh line] != -1} {
    send -- "$line\r"
}
close $fh
interact
```

When I run this manually from the command line, everything works fine. But when I try to add this to a bash script file and run the script it doesn't work. This is what I write in the bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

expect <<'finished'
spawn ./my_interactive_program 
set fh [open MBC4_Row1_Pitch1.in r]
while {[gets $fh line] != -1} {
    send -- "$line\r"
}
close $fh
interact
finished
```

It just echoes:

```
spawn ./my_interactive_program
```

Any ideas what can I do to fix this? Am I doing something wrong?
Thank you very much.

Comment: add `exp_internal 1` before the spawn command and see what expect's debugging output tells you. Also, run the bash script with `bash -x myscript`

Answer (score 0):

The input redirection in the bash script prevents providing interactive input.
Just do without bash and make an expect script of your working code:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn ./my_interactive_program 
set fh [open MBC4_Row1_Pitch1.in r]
while {[gets $fh line] != -1} {
    send -- "$line\r"
}
close $fh
interact
```